# Custom charts Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset, gantt-chart

Does someone have an experience with custom charts within Apache Superset?

I'm actually trying to figure it out, how to create a Gantt chart or something similar to it, so that i could represent durations of some non-overlapping actions happened during 24h period.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.